# Select couchbase nested object

Tags: couchbase

I have a bunch of documents with a structure like this:

```
{
  "month": 11,
  "year": 2017,
  //other fields
  "Cars":[
  {
    "CarId": 123,
    // other fields
  },
  {
    "CarId": 456,
    // other fields
  }
  // other cars
   ]
}
```

I am searching for a concrete car instance with `id = 456`. So far I have:

```
SELECT Cars
FROM DevBucket
WHERE year = 2017
    AND month = 11
    AND [CarId=456]
```

Couchbase returns correct document (which contains target car). However the output includes an array of all `Car` nodes within a document, but I'd like to have a single car (as if I use `SELECT Cars[1]` in the example above)

Search through couchbase tutorials didn't give me an answer. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`UNNEST` clause](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html#story-h2-5) you can perform "a join of the nested array with its parent object."  This will produce an object for each nested element that includes the nested element as a top-level field, along with the rest of the original document (nested elements, and all).

This query will retrieve the car with an id of `456` when its parent object has a month and year of 11/2017.

```
SELECT car
FROM DevBucket db
UNNEST Cars car
WHERE car.CarId = 456 
    AND db.year = 2017
    AND db.month = 11;
```

Create this index for a quicker lookup than what you'll get with a Primary Index:

```
CREATE INDEX cars_index 
    ON DevBucket(DISTINCT ARRAY car.CarId FOR car IN Cars END);
```

For more information on `UNNEST` see [NEST and UNNEST: Normalizing and Denormalizing JSON on the Fly](https://dzone.com/articles/nesting-and-unnesting-in-couchbase-n1ql)